# Downvotes. Why?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it poor ettiquette to downvote without leaving a comment?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/is-it-poor-ettiquette-to-downvote-without-leaving-a-comment)

People are getting down-votes on their posts and there is no explanation. Nobody learns from this. This hasn't happened to me, but I'm totally baffled about some of the questions that get down-voted without comment.

If you want a poster and readers to learn from your down-vote, please say something. Not to be like one of the sarcastic SO people, but if you don't feel strongly enough about your down-vote to explain it, maybe you haven't thought it through completely.

Please be fair to the people with questions and those who want their questions considered in the future when casting a down-vote.

{preparing myself for a flurry of down-votes right now}

Comment: I think this is the natural consequence of removing the cost for downvoting on questions.

Comment: -1 for not bothering to search for the duplicate before posting your rant. ;-)